# Random number starting points

Tags: random, awk

The `awk` manual says `srand` "sets the seed (starting point) for `rand()`". I used `srand(5)` with the following code:

```
awk 'BEGIN {srand(5);while(1)print rand()}'> /var/tmp/rnd
```

It generates numbers like:

```
0.177399
0.340855
0.0256178
0.838417
0.0195347
0.29598
```

Can you explain how `srand(5)` generates the "starting point" with the above output?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed

Answer (score 1):

The starting point is called the seed.  It is given to the first iteration of the rand function.   After that rand uses the previous value it got when calculating  the old number --  to generate the next number.  Using a prime number for the seed is a good idea.

Comment: Close, but not quite. A random number generator maintains *some* kind of internal state, and generates numbers by advancing that state each time it is called. That state may or may not contain actual previous output. Seeding it uses the number given to initialize that internal state in an algorithm-dependent way. Forget primes, if it cares at all what kind of seed is passed, it is hopelessly broken.

Comment: Thanks Lee and Jim. So if I understand it correctly, the seed is mainly conerned with the internal state of a PRNG. It has nothing to do with the lower bound of the random number generated. To generate a random number between a and b, I should use a+rand()*(b-a). Am I correct?

Comment: @Lee Daniel Crocker  - FWIW - an internal value created during calculation.  Not necessarily the output. It really doesn't matter - if my sentence did not convey the meaning correctly then it failed in that respect.  Thanks. +1

Answer (score 1):

PRNGs (pseudo-random number generators) produce random values by keeping some kind of internal state which can be advanced through a series of values whose repeating period is very large, and whose successive values have very few apparent statistical correlations as long as we use far fewer of them. But nonetheless, its values are a deterministic sequence.

"Seeding" a PRNG is basically selecting what point in the deterministic sequence to start at. The algorithm will take the number passed as the seed and compute (in some algorithm-specific way) where to start in the sequence. The actual value of the seed is irrelevant--the algorithm should not depend on it in any way.

But, although the seed value itself does not directly participate in the PRNG algorithm, it does uniquely identify the starting point in the sequence, so if you give a particular seed and then generate a sequence of values, seeding again with the same value should cause the PRNG to generate the same sequence of values.